# How to place admob code without xml layout

Tags: java, android, layout, admob

Anyone please help me to place admob code but without xml layout. The ads is not show.
Thank you.
This is the code:

When build, the ads is not show, but build is success.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // MainView activity
    MainView view;

    public static final String WIDTH = "width";
    public static final String HEIGHT = "height";
    public static final String SCORE = "score";
    public static final String HIGH_SCORE = "high score temp";
    public static final String UNDO_SCORE = "undo score";
    public static final String CAN_UNDO = "can undo";
    public static final String UNDO_GRID = "undo";
    public static final String GAME_STATE = "game state";
    public static final String UNDO_GAME_STATE = "undo game state";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    view = new MainView(getBaseContext());

    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    view.hasSaveState = settings.getBoolean("save_state", false);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        if (savedInstanceState.getBoolean("hasState")) {
            load();
        }
    }

    // adview code
    AdView adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx");
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);

    // ads parameter
    LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    adView.setLayoutParams(params1);

    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    // layout list
    layout.addView(view);
    layout.addView(adView);

    setContentView(layout);

    // ads request
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
    .build();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the `AdRequest` to `AdView` to display the Ads on the view after creating the `AdRequest` instance.

```
adView.loadAd(request);
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Libin. Work like a charm. And, how to make ads show center of the screen?

Comment: More than 12 hours I am still confusing with this layout. mmm